# Run msbuild post-build task for few projects or solution, and run it once per build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, build-automation

I have solution in Visual studio with multiple projects. I would like to execute some post-build task (it copies files to some folder) when any of the projects gets built and **do it once**.

So, if I build one project that has dependencies on 3 other projects, my post-build task will be executed 4 times. How can I make it to execute only once when projects are built? 
Option with solution-wide post-build target does not work since it get triggered only when whole solution is built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating separate empty project, referencing subset of the projects and adding post-build tast:

```
<Target Name="DeployJsPerfFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(WorkgroupDir)" Command="rake suite:deploy" />
 </Target>
```

(I wasn't able to use Copy task because we are using Rake tasks for deployment)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I would import a common .targets file into each project file.

```
<Import Project="..\AfterBuild.targets" />
```

Above is assuming you place it one folder up. Make sure its inserted after all other imports (especially the core one e.g. Microsoft.CSharp.targets)

Create the AfterBuild.targets file e.g:

```
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">

        <ItemGroup>
            <!-- Items to copy -->
            <CopyItems Include="c:\xyz\*" />
        </ItemGroup>
            <!-- Set the source to the item group and the destination folder  and the SkipUnchangedFiles property -->
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(CopyItems)" DestinationFolder="c:\xyz\destination-folder" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" SkipUnchangedFiles="true"/>

    </Target>

</Project>
```

Note the SkipUnchangedFiles property of the MsBuild [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) task. If you build any project it will copy only if the source files are changed from the target ones. If you build all projects files then the source files will only be copied once.

Comment: This will still be executed 4 times. See Incremental builds an example is here http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/67/incremental-builds-in-msbuild-and-how-to-avoid-breaking-them

Comment: your stated outcome was to only copy the files once. This achieves the outcome